# Multiple regex to match file extension with version

Tags: regex, node.js

My current regex is like so

```
/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i
```

I'm trying to modify it to support matching when the extension has get parameters at the end of it so all of the below formats would match

```
../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0
../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular'
```

How can I modify it to support these?

Comment: What have you tried? What are the rules? Does just moving the end of line anchor suffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the URLs to be parsed follow [proper formatting](http://www.w3.org/TR/url/) (where only one '?' delimiter can be used to signify the start of the query) you could do:

```
 /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)(?:\?.*|)$/i
```

```js
var urls = [
  '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg',
  '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0',
  '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular'
];

var matches = urls.map(function(url) { return url.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)(?:\?.*|)$/i); });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(matches, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Alternatively you could use Node's [`url.parse()`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost):

```
var url = require('url');
var urlObj = url.parse(URL_STRING);
var matches = urlObj.pathname.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i);
```

Comment: wouldn't the first one require a ? after the second parenthetical since it may not be there? e.g. /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)(?:\?.*|)?$/i Or is that what the ?: does? (not as familiar with js regex vs. pcre)